# Fastlane error: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '*'

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

Currently, I am using the same process for building in Xcode directly and in Fastlane. But while it is working perfectly in Xcode (building and archiving both working fine), in Fastlane it throw an error and tells me `ARCHIVE FAILED`. It looks like the Fastlane is trying to find the iOS App Development provisioning profile while it only finds App Distribution profiles I assume. Is there a way to get around it, like if I can build the app with command line (without Fastlane) and use Fastlane to deploy the `.ipa` file I have created?

The error shown in Fastlane log:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                     Summary for gym 2.208.0                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| workspace                            | ./platforms/ios/myproject.xcworkspace                      |
| configuration                        | Release                                                   |
| scheme                               | myproject                                                  |
| output_directory                     | .                                                         |
| output_name                          | output                                                    |
| clean                                | true                                                      |
| export_method                        | app-store                                                 |
| skip_profile_detection               | false                                                     |
| destination                          | generic/platform=iOS                                      |
| silent                               | false                                                     |
| skip_package_ipa                     | false                                                     |
| skip_package_pkg                     | false                                                     |
| build_path                           | /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-08-01 |
| result_bundle                        | false                                                     |
| buildlog_path                        | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                        |
| xcodebuild_formatter                 | xcpretty                                                  |
| xcodebuild_command                   | xcodebuild                                                |
| skip_package_dependencies_resolution | false                                                     |
| disable_package_automatic_updates    | false                                                     |
| use_system_scm                       | false                                                     |
| xcode_path                           | /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app                            |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+

[20:25:28]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./platforms/ios/myproject.xcworkspace -scheme myproject -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-08-01/output\ 2022-08-01\ 20.25.28.xcarchive clean archive | tee /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/myproject-myproject.log | xcpretty
[20:25:35]: ▸ Clean Succeeded
[20:25:46]: ▸ ❌  error: No profiles for 'com.myprojectapp.myproject' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.myprojecttapp.myproject'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'myproject' from project 'myproject')
[20:25:46]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

Code signing settings:

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
|             Summary for code signing settings               |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| use_automatic_signing | true                                |
| path                  | ./platforms/ios/myproject.xcodeproj |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you don't have automatic signing disabled and you need to either enable it or go to your Xcode project and select the right provisioning profile for what you're trying to build via Fastlane by going to `Your target>Signing & Capabilities` and select the proper provisioning profiles and development teams

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, in my case this code is running in Github Action, which doesn't allow me to make adjustments through XCode manually. Is there a way to adjust that, maybe by modifying some code inside the project?

Comment: Hey Terry. Yes, you can commit the changes to your project in the Signing and Capabilites and let run it in Github Actions for CI/CD. Also, you need to make sure that those profiles exist in the first place before trying to run Github Actions in those machines either by installing them if you have access to them or by downloading them each time you run these builds

Comment: Have you tried to build in your local machine with fastlane before sending it to Github Actions? That may give you a hint if you have a misconfiguration in your Github Actions machines

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, I will try and let you know when I have time (guess would be quite a while).

Comment: How can I enable automatic signing in Fastlane?